# Is there any possible way I can send GET requests faster with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm currently using Node.js, i want to send multiple requests in a loop as fast as possible. I mean that they are sent very quickly in succession. The fastest I can get them to be sent to far is by using a for loop. Here is an example:

```
request({
            url: "http://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&CreatorID=1&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&IncludeNotForSale=true&LegendExpanded=true&Category=0&PageNumber=" + (pageNumber++),
            method: 'GET'
        }, function(err, res, body) {
// do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Using a for loop - around the async requests - is simply (possibly massively) parallelizing the outgoing requests. It doesn't make any one request faster (and will actually make some requests slower, while still increasing the throughput); making individual requests faster depends a good bit on the remote server/API.

Comment: What about the above is 'disjointed'? If there is a specific concept that could be clarified in my comment, please use concise language to draw it out instead of devolving to an opinionated snark ~ thanks.

Comment: I agree with user here, on both his comments. I would add a question or two to your question: what _part_ specifically do you want to speed up? Also what node version do you have, in some cases it might be a limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) for this task.

Comment: If the OP runs the shown code above (which creates asynchronous requests) in a loop it will already been running in parallel - albeit without much control. Maybe an example of *how* that library might be used would be useful..